# Customise sorcery's require_login function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

Is there a way to customise [sorcery's](https://github.com/Sorcery/sorcery) `require_login` function to provide a flash message and to redirect to page other than root_path e.g. to a login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by overriding sorcery's not_authenticated function, which it calls  when the user is not logged in, for example

## app/controller/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :require_login

  def not_authenticated
    flash[:alert] = 'Customised warning'
    redirect_to main_app.login_path
  end

end
```

Also make sure that the rails_admin controllers are inheriting from your application controller;

## config/initializers/rails_admin.rb

RailsAdmin.config do |config|
...
config.parent_controller = 'ApplicationController'
end